# Spam Email from me to me

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, bitcoin

I have just received an email with the from address being the same as my own email address but Google has correctly classified it as spam and it went straight to my Spam folder.

The content of the email is quite similar to this. Now, obviously this appears to be a spam email by some scammers who are looking to make a quick buck. The Bitcoin Wallet also appears on the Bitcoin Abuse Database and a lot of people have reported similar emails.

Can someone please confirm that this is just a spam email and that they do not have access to may accounts. I use 2FA for my Gmail account, so there is no way they could have accessed my Gmail account.

If this is not a scam, what could I possibly do to protect my laptop?

Funnily enough, when I received this email I had not changed my Gmail password at all. I have changed it now.

> Hi, dear user of gmail.com
>
> We have installed one RAT software into you device For this moment
>   your email account is hacked too. I know your password. I logged in to
>   your account and wrote this letter to you from there.
>
> Changed your password? You're doing great! But my software recognizes
>   every such action. I'm updating passwords! I'm always one step
>   ahead....
>
> So... I have downloaded all confidential information from your system
>   and I got some more evidence. The most interesting moment that I have
>   discovered are videos records where you masturbating.
>
> I posted Spelevo Exploit modification on porn site, and then you
>   installed my malicious code (trojan) on your operation system. When
>   you clicked the button Play on porn video, at that moment my trojan
>   was downloaded to your device. After installation, your front camera
>   shoots video every time you masturbate, in addition, the software is
>   synchronized with the video you choose. For the moment, the software
>   has harvrested all your contact information from social networks and
>   email addresses. If you need to erase all of your collected data and
>   videos, send me $718 in BTC (crypto currency).
>
> This is my Bitcoin wallet: 13yAsTuS6MyjNUYde4EBabTZJFfZBRTZu1
>
> You have 48 hours after reading this letter. After your transaction I
>   will erase all your data. Otherwise, I will send a video with your
>   sweepstakes to all your colleagues, friends and relatives!!!
>
> P.S. I ask you not to reply to this email, this is impossible (the
>   sender's address is your own address). And henceforth be more careful!
>   Please visit only secure sites!
>
> Bye,Bye...

Comment: This is an obvious scam.  However, asking about if an email is legitmant, is out of scope here at Super User (or really any Stack Exchange community).

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! I had added an additional edit as well - if this isn't a scam, then is there anything I can do to protect my laptop?

Comment: @ConcernedGmailUser - **There is no chance the email you recieved isn't a scam** If you system had a RAT installed on it, then you would have to format your device, and reinstall your OS.  This easily could be a duplicate of the question we typically use to close question about malicious software.  This type of scam is the same type of scam you get from "friends" who are "in another country but they need money for some reason".  **Stop worrying about a scam.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the detailed comment. I started to worry with the double-negative in the first sentence, but the last line in bold is fantastic to hear. :-)

Comment: Not really I good candidate for the proposed dup since the user's machine isn't infected.

Answer (score 1):

No one can verify they DON'T have your accounts, because that in itself would be bad even if us 'good' guys have it. I would strongly speculate it is spam & trying to scare you into doing something. Your wording seems to indicate you believe that as well. It's very easy to spoof an email address. If you are REALLY paranoid you could change passwords for all websites where you use that email address & your old gmail password (that you indicated you changed recently). If they SOMEHOW have your gmail password they can try it at other sites & maybe do harm there (not everywhere). I'd personally ignore it, you could also see if your email & password has been seen in a hacked website database via this site: https://haveibeenpwned.com/

If you're worried about infections get a [reputable antivirus](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/) (hereafter AV) & run a full scan, people seem to enjoy malwarebytes for cleaning up infections. A lot of the major AV have (free) offline scanners that boot to a USB or CD that work really well. I had an I.T. tech coworker who said he charged doctors $50+ just to insert a CD which does all the cleaning & hand it back, about 5min of work for him :(

Comment: Thanks! If this question is not relevant here (as per Ramhound), this can be marked as deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the edit as well. It is an office provided laptop and they already have some antivirus running, so I will just leave it at that.

Comment: @ConcernedGmailUser - Unless you are performing the actions, described in the email in front of the device, that is how you can easily determine this email is a scam.  It takes zero effort to make an email appear as it was sent by somebody else.  I could write an email from Bill Gates, and offer you the chance to become the next CEO of Microsoft, in exchange of a video of you performing the chicken dance.  **The email is obviously fake.**  This will be my last comment on the subject..

Comment: I'd run the full antivirus scan just to ease everyone's mind. Also please upvote all answers & comments you find helpful & accept anyone's answer/response you like. I do a bit of this free work here for those points it gives me ;). Here are some links to techniques scammers might use to trick people:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_support_scam
https://www.aarp.org/money/scams-fraud/info-2019/tech-support.html